# Does the C++ standard include what standard headers must include?

Tags: c++

On visualstudio the header "thread" includes all of the following headers:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
```

So now we can just use this:

```
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
```

So on VS you dont have to include "chrono" again to be able to use 1s 1000ms etc.
Can we assume that  always includes  on all platforms? Or more general, does the standard say what headers standard headers must include?

Comment: No, there is no such guarantee.  The standard only defines, what a header must provide, e.g. [[thread.threads](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.threads)].

Comment: You should always include yourself all the headers required by the code your write and never rely on nested includes.

Comment: I believe that every C++ compiler has his own standard library, so header files will include what ever they want. For example, the `thread` header for TDM GCC does not include headers such as `iosfwd` or `exception`

Comment: You *could* look it up yourself: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf

Comment: right....i did that, but not being able to find it doesnt mean its not in there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no such guarantee.  The standard only dictates, which definitions a header must provide.  In the case of [[thread.threads](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.threads)] you will find that the synopsis does not contain any `#include`.  This can be different for other headers but still then, only the listed ones are required, see e.g. [[bitset](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/bitset)].

For example, the `thread` header for TDM GCC 4.9.2 does not include header files such as `iosfwd` or `exception`.

As an explicit example, the following compiles on my GCC 5 but not on GCC 7 because in an update to the standard library the GCC maintainers decided that `algorithm` should no longer include `numeric`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4};
    int sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), int{0});
}
```

---

That being said, you should always include the all required top-level headers which provide the symbols you need.